# Как сериализовать строку с координатами в массив? JSON

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

Возникла проблема. У меня получается передать объект JSON формата таким образом. Внимание на поля begin и end

```
[
    {
      "title": "asdfgf",
      "percent": 100,
      "begin": "55.681320655330616,49.275157732737206",
      "end": "77.01408793659662,70.15013349999994",
      "pipelinepoint_pipeline": [
        {
          "address": [
            65.96250723703659,
            99.32982099999995
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
 ]
```

Но нужно получить JSON объект формата. Внимание на поля begin и end

```
[
    {
      "title": "asdfgf",
      "percent": 100,
      "begin": [55.681320655330616,49.275157732737206],
      "end": [77.01408793659662,70.15013349999994],
      "pipelinepoint_pipeline": [
        {
          "address": [
            65.96250723703659,
            99.32982099999995
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
 ]
```

serializers.py

```
class PipelineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pipelinepoint_pipeline = PipelinePointSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Pipeline
        fields = ['title', 'percent', 'begin', 'end', 
                                       'pipelinepoint_pipeline']
```

models.py

```
class Pipeline(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    percent = models.PositiveIntegerField(null = True, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)])
    begin = models.ForeignKey(Factory, on_delete = models.CASCADE, 
                                 to_field="address")
    end = models.ForeignKey(OilSump, on_delete = models.CASCADE, 
                                 to_field="address")
```

views.py

```
class PipeLineListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Pipeline.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PipelineSerializer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался сам.

```
class PipelineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pipelinepoint_pipeline = PipelinePointSerializer(many=True)
    begin = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    end = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Pipeline
        fields = ['title', 'percent', 'begin', 'end', 
                                    'pipelinepoint_pipeline']

    def get_begin(self, obj):
       return [float(i) for i in obj.begin.address.split(',')]

    def get_end(self, obj):
       return [float(i) for i in obj.end.address.split(',')]
```